# Confirmation message while inputing payments

Tags: e-commerce, validation, messages, payment, confirmation

We have electronic fund transfer code which is now being replaced by a new piece of regulation, the ePayments code. And we wanted to provide an onscreen warning message for customers completing Pay Anyone Transactions using via web, mobile, tablet. The current flow (for mobile) what we have is to throw a overlay window with the message containing cancel and confirm buttons with the warning message. Now, we got a new challenge which is show the warning message different type of payment pages like

```
Pay Anyone 
Pay Anyone - Confirm Details
Pay BPay Bills
Pay BPAY Bills - Confirm Details
Schedule Multiple Payments/Transfers
Schedule Multiple Payments/Transfers - Review Request
International Money Transfer - Beneficiary Details  
International Money Transfer - Transfer Details
International Money Transfer - Review Request
```

Does it make sense to have the same warning message on different types of payments which customer makes or can have payment type specific warning message?

Comment: What is the purpose of the "warning message"? What does it say?

Comment: @Matt Obee The purpose of this warning message is to provide a message to customers warning them to check Pay Anyone payment details because if they send money to the wrong person, bank may not be able to retrieve it.

Comment: @ravi then you need a confirmation dialog for the details

Comment: @ratchet freak sorry if my question was not clear, it more towards the type of message i need to show depending on the type of payment customers do instead of showing same generic message for every payment type(bill pay/international payments/transfers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the overlay warning message would not do any good to the user experience.

Firstly, once the filled out details are overlayed with the warning message asking you to check the details the only way for a user to check them is to close the warning by clicking cancel. Which could be interpreted as canceling and erasing all of the details the user has entered.

Secondly, let's be honest, any online operation related to money is triple checked by the user. This being said, we still make mistakes and we need some sort of a reminder to check it one more time. The message, however, should not be as intrusive as your suggestion.

I believe that having a good mental flow in any application is what makes it enjoyable to use. I suggest you simply let the user fill out the details and then after clicking the submit button take him to the next screen with all the details as uneditable text with a "Confirm" and "Change" buttons below it. The verb "confirm" will make the user scan the details one more time and if they find a mistake they can click "Change" which will take them to the previous screen.

In my suggestion above you would not even have to worry about the specific warning text as it has been replaced by "Confirm" button.

Comment: A related problem is that the payment details form probably includes a field for Payee Name, which might cause the user to think the Payee Name will be used to verify the destination in the transfer process. At NAB they at least provide a sidebar note with the text "Warning: Please ensure all details are correct. NAB cannot check the account name matches the BSB or account number. An incorrect BSB or account number will result in your money being paid to the wrong account and may result in the loss of your funds". Dunno what CBA or WBC does.